# Activity needs to be paused until child Activity runs (Android)

Tags: android

```
1. theNewIntent = new Intent(parentActivity,NewScreen.class);
2. parentActivity.startActivity(theNewIntent);
3. Log.d(TAG,"RETURNED BACK TO HOME VIEW");
```

Here i creates a new intent and starts a new activity. I want my current activity to be on hold until i finish the newly created activity. What i want is not to execute line 3 until "NewScreen" activity is finished.

Can anyone suggest me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant really achieve this without some kind of synchronization. The easiest thing to do would be to call startActivityForResult() and put your log message in onActivityResult(...). This would give you the synchronicity but would still kind of break your flow over 2 methods. The issue is that startActivity() is a non blocking call.

Your current activity will be on hold in the sense that it wont get any user feedback until the activity on top of it is cancelled.